# ubuntu server restarting instead of shutting down

Tags: 14.04, server, shutdown, restart

Whenever I try to shutdown my pc by using `sudo shutdown -... now` (it doesn't matter what I fill in for the `...`), it always shutdowns down for about 3-4 seconds, and than just powers up again. I'm sure WOL is disabled, and just to be sure I tested it with ethernet cable unplugged.

It's a fresh install of ubuntu server 14.04. It's also a new pc so I do not have any prior experience with it.

Any help would be very much appreciated

Comment: There might also be a BIOS/UEFI setting for "power on after power off" which decides what happens after shutdown.

Comment: Had the same problem some time ago, can you try with another (older) kernel?

Comment: Some time ago I've found the same problem reported in a bug report for ubuntu-mate (as this is what I've used). And just recently
the bug **seems to be SOLVED after the last kernel upgrade**!!!
I am not very sure about though. Need additional testing.
But today with all the rest in the setup unchanged the laptop (HP probook) started to poweroff normally. Current kernel is: $ uname -a Linux uhp 4.4.0-62-generic #83-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 18 14:10:15 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux What about the other affected people?

Answer (score 1):

Just had this problem with 14.04 on a Gigabyte GA-MA78GM-S2H based desktop. Tried all the BIOS settings I've seen suggested around the web with no luck.

Thought it might be a USB related wake. Used non USB mouse and keyboard and problem solved.

Also USB keyboard adapter will work, but not one for the mouse, which is a little odd.