# Why isn't my Ubuntu turning off when I want it to?

Tags: xubuntu

I have tried everything from terminal commands and grub updates and no matter what I try it will NEVER shut off. It always restarts after 2-3 seconds. I am on latest Ubuntu and installed 2 hours ago and I am still battling this system flaw -_-.. Please, someone save me from this. Solution is much needed!

Comment: You should probably try [booting without acpi enabled](http://askubuntu.com/questions/160036/how-do-i-disable-acpi-when-booting).

Comment: Like I said [earlier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26196450/does-anyone-know-why-ubuntu-cant-shut-down-even-though-i-ask-it-to#26196450), this [has been asked before](http://askubuntu.com/questions/515225/ubuntu-server-restarting-instead-of-shutting-down). If there are no (useful) answers or comments, [start a bounty](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218442/theres-a-question-that-has-no-answer-should-i-ask-it-again-or-start-a-bounty). If you don't have enough reputation to start a bounty, you may just find someone who will. If you play nice.

Comment: What hardware are you using?

Comment: I found yet another duplicate; I hope one of its answers solves your problem. http://askubuntu.com/questions/452750/reboot-after-shutdown-ubuntu-14-04-also-12-04-dell-latitude-e7440

Comment: Please file a bug report on Launchpad for this.