# Ubuntu 16.04 on a i7-6440 and Quadro K1200 reboots after software shutdown

Tags: 16.04, shutdown, reboot, gpu

I am facing a strange problem on my ubuntu 16.04 for Lenevo M83 box, having i7 6400 chipset and Nvidia Quadro P1200 gpu card, it restarts even when I choose shutdown through OS.
I tried few things suggested on other threads but that did not help. Only when I do a hard shutdown like powering down my cpu, does the machine shutdown.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 16 reboots seconds after shutdown](http://askubuntu.com/questions/760851/ubuntu-16-reboots-seconds-after-shutdown)

Comment: Android Dev this question seems similar but none of the solutions there solves my issue.