# Ubuntu 19.04 restart after shutdown

Tags: shutdown, 19.04, reboot, restart

I have installed Ubuntu 19.04, And I have an issue that Ubuntu Automatically restart after I shut down my laptop.

Ubuntu: 19.04,
Machine: Acer V5-471,
*single boot

I have tried everything on the internet.

Some solution on the internet I tried, But nothing works :-(

[Ubuntu 16 reboots seconds after shutdown](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760851/ubuntu-16-reboots-seconds-after-shutdown)

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2188726

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2390730

Answer (score 0):

I have only encountered this once before and solved it by disabling **wake on LAN** in the system BIOS.

Comment: thanks, I have tried it too but it doesn't work or me.