# Shut Down Problem

Tags: 20.04, xubuntu, shutdown, system, restart

I am using Linux 20.04 in HP Pro book.Everything is working fine except that when I shutdown the laptop it automatically restarts after 2-3 seconds.So basically I cannot shut down my system.Before Linux I was using Windows 10, never had this problem.

Anyone Please guide how to fix it?
Thank You!

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760851/ubuntu-16-reboots-seconds-after-shutdown)

Comment: Look at the logs. Just after the shutdown/restart, `sudo journalctl --since="-5 minutes"`